# Showing util.inherits is not a function while importing jwt in vue vite.js

Tags: vue.js, vite

[image]

Showing util.inherits is not a function while importing jwt in vue vite

Comment: Hi! Were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

since util is a node built in it won't get polyfill by vite, add this plugin to your project

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills
```

and then you add this to your vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
})
```